# How to inject a Class with constructor into Resource Class Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, resources

> Getting error in Resource Laravel
> "App\Http\Resources\OrderResource::__construct(): Argument #2
> ($orderLogRepository) must be of type
> App\Interfaces\OrderLogRepositoryInterface, int given, called in
> /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Collections/Traits/EnumeratesValues.php
> on line 355"

I am injecting a class with constructor into OrderResource.php file. But it's giving the previous error! I didn't find any clue of this.

```
class OrderResource extends JsonResource
{
    public $orderLogRepository;

    public function __construct($resource, OrderLogRepositoryInterface $orderLogRepository)
    {
        $this->orderLogRepository = $orderLogRepository;
        parent::__construct($resource);
    }
}
```

Calling that `resource` with collection.
`OrderResource::collection($orders);`

Comment: Where are you instantiating `OrderResource`? The error suggests you're passing the wrong argument.

Comment: Calling that resource with collection. OrderResource::collection($orders);

Comment: The `OrderResource::collection` calls `mapInto` on collection objects, and if you follow that method, you'll end up here: `trait EnumeratesValues::mapInto`


As you can see, it calls `new $class($value, $key);` so the $key int is passed instead of the implementation of your interface.

Unfortunately I have not found how to do DI, but at least you'll know why this doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You have to do something like this.

we can't able to call interface through constructor. so we need to try different method.

first todo:
'is_cart' => \App::make('App\Interfaces\Cart\CartInterfaces')->checkProductIDInCart($this->id),

for my example:

```
 public function toArray($request)
{
    
    return [
        'id' => $this->id,
        'encrypt_id'   => \Crypt::encrypt($this->id), 
        'is_cart' => \App::make('App\Interfaces\Cart\CartInterfaces')->checkProductIDInCart($this->id),
    ];
}
```